# How do I dynamically draw existing points from a data set in a Python program

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, matplotlib-animation

I've this Python script to dynamically update a chart as values are added to a csv file:

```py
import numpy as np
from itertools import count
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation

plt.style.use('fivethirtyeight')

x_vals = []
y_vals = []

index = count()


def animate(i):
    data = pd.read_csv('csv_data.csv')
    x = data['x_value']
    y1 = data['total_1']
    y2 = data['total_2']

    plt.cla()
    plt.plot(x, y1, label='Channel 1')
    plt.plot(x, y2, label='Channel 2')

    plt.legend(loc='upper left')

    plt.tight_layout()


ani = FuncAnimation(plt.gcf(), animate, frames=np.arange(0, 11, 0.1), interval=1000)

plt.show()
```

This is what my csv data initially looks like:

```
x_value,total_1,total_2
0,1000,1000
1,1002,1001
2,1004,999
3,1006,1004
4,1002,1003
5,999,1003
6,1003,1001
7,1011,1004
8,1008,1000
9,1010,1000
10,1012,999
```

If I run my program the chart appears with all 11 points for each line and dynamically adds each new one after that. Is it possible to edit this code so that the initial 11 points get drawn dynamically when the program is run and if so how do I do that? I wish for each point to be drawn every second.

Comment: I assume you could use a slice for the first `n` points. So after you initialized `y2`, you could indent everything and have a loop like `for n in range(10): plt.plot(x[n:], y1[n:], label='Channel 1')`. *Maybe*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way you could get the 11 points to get drawn dynamically at every 1 second interval

```
import numpy as np
from itertools import count
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.style.use('fivethirtyeight')

plt.figure()

data = pd.read_csv('csv_data.csv')
x = data['x_value']
y1 = data['total_1']
y2 = data['total_2']

line1 = plt.plot(x[0], y1[0], 'ok', lw=1.5, label='Channel 1',color='black')
line2 = plt.plot(x[0], y2[0], '+', lw=1.5, label='Channel 2',color='red')
plt.title('Channels', fontsize=16)
plt.ylabel('Channel', fontsize=12)
plt.xlabel('x_value', fontsize=12)

plt.ion()   # set interactive mode
plt.show()
for i, item in data.iterrows():

    line1 = plt.plot(x[i], y1[i], 'ok', lw=1.5,color='black')
    line2 = plt.plot(x[i], y2[i], '+', lw=1.5,color='red')
    plt.legend()
    plt.gcf().canvas.draw()
    plt.pause(1)
```

Comment: that seems to plot only the first 3 points for each line then the window crashes. I'm trying to figure out what's causing it to crash.

Comment: `for i, item in enumerate(data):` loops through each column rather than each row. As there are only 3 columns this is why it finishes then. How do I loop through each row?

Comment: Ah! Made the change. This should loop over rows.

Comment: @runnerpaul If this answer helped resolve your problem, you want to check the green mark. This will help keep the focus on unanswered questions.

Comment: Cheers. I opted for `for i, row in data.iterrows():` but your answer is good. Thanks for the help.